# Drupal flash questions

Tags: drupal, video, flash

I received from the client .flv files, and used SWF Tools to embed a different video in the right sidebar of each page.

Now the client wants that changed, to .swf files.  (I understand that both the .swf file and accompanying .flv file need to be present for this to work).

Do I still use SWF Tools, or something else?

Thanks in advance.

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWF Tools will work just fine. The SWF file basically just serves as a conduit through which the FLV is streamed.

Comment: In the SWF Tools module, there are a number of players listed.  Do I use one of these for a .swf file?

Comment: I've read pages of the above, and I'm lost.  In the SWF Tools module, I tried "SWFObject2", but it just doesn't do anything.  The .swf file is just enclosed in an anchor link.  Any way you could be a little more specific?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you're running into. So, here's a GotDrupal screencast showing the whole nine yards. http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-multimedia-using-swf-tools

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module.

Comment: Should be noted that the Media module is Drupal 7 only